# C# RegEx for decimal number or zero (0)

Tags: c#, regex

This gets all numbers but not floating numbers

```
Regex(@"^\d+$")
```

I need it to get these values as well:

```
1234.12345545
0
12313
12313.13
-12131
-1313.13211312
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For matching all of the above; the most appropriate regex is probably

```
@"^[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?$"
```

This matches all of the above; but not numbers on the format `.3456`.

It also matches numbers on the format +123 and -1234.5678

Comment: sorry, i checked again and it gets all numbers except decimals.

Comment: @"^\d+(.\d+)?$" -works, what if i wanted to include negatives as well? (ex. -123 -1231.12 -12312.13123213131)

Comment: works! what if i wanted to include .3456? I just remove \. right?

Comment: This will match also numbers with leading zeros like 0001, not sure if this is wanted.

Comment: @stema: Well, your regex is indeed more complete. But it's hard keeping up with the user requirements on this one; question has been updated about <del>5</del> 2 times. ;)

Comment: sorry for the edits, but will this @"^[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?$" work for .3456 if i make it like this? @"^[+-]?\d+(\d+)?$"

Comment: @PodMays: No; you need it to be `^[+-]?(\d*)(\.\d+)?$` for that

Comment: @Williham, I am sure he will find more requirements when he is working with this ;). But anyway +1 for you for your patience with the changing requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Try this here

```
^(?:[-+]?[1-9]\d*|0)?(?:\.\d+)?$
```

This will additionally match the empty string.

[See it online here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2tpmr)

If matching the empty string is not wanted, then you can add a length check to your regex like

```
^(?=.+)(?:[-+]?[1-9]\d*|0)?(?:\.\d+)?$
```

The positive lookahead `(?=.+)` ensures that there is at least 1 character